# What is the best way to redirect 2500 links after relaunch?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

We have rebuilt a shop in Magento 1.9. The old shop was a "modifed shop".
Unfortunately, all links within the page structure change.

like this:

Main Category

myshopdomain.com/Category:::121_428.html

myshopdomain.com/category.html

SubCategory

myshopdomain.com/Category/Sub-Category:::158_142.html

myshopdomain.com/category/sub-category.html

Product

myshopdomain.com/Category/Sub-Category/Product:::4518.html

myshopdomain.com/category/sub-category/product.html

These are about 2500 links.
How do I solve this?
Do we have to enter all this manually in the backend?
or maybe better in the .htaccess

like:
0. convert to lowercase
1. cut in front of ":::"
2. ad ".html"
3. Forwarding.

hmm ...

Maybe someone has a tip

greetings
Heiko

Comment: sure, use simple regex and rewrite pattern